# How to collect all vertex and edge properties along path, with Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Here's a really simple query:

```
g.V('customerId').out().path()
```

The JSON output of this is

```
{  
   "requestId":"96b26c1d-d032-2004-d36e-c700bd6db2a2",
   "status":{  
      "message":"",
      "code":200,
      "attributes":{  
         "@type":"g:Map",
         "@value":[  

         ]
      }
   },
   "result":{  
      "data":{  
         "@type":"g:List",
         "@value":[  
            {  
               "@type":"g:Path",
               "@value":{  
                  "labels":{  
                     "@type":"g:List",
                     "@value":[  
                        {  
                           "@type":"g:Set",
                           "@value":[  

                           ]
                        },
                        {  
                           "@type":"g:Set",
                           "@value":[  

                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "objects":{  
                     "@type":"g:List",
                     "@value":[  
                        {  
                           "@type":"g:Vertex",
                           "@value":{  
                              "id":"customerId",
                              "label":"customer"
                           }
                        },
                        {  
                           "@type":"g:Vertex",
                           "@value":{  
                              "id":"e:customerIdemail@email.com",
                              "label":"email"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "meta":{  
         "@type":"g:Map",
         "@value":[  

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Now, a customer vertex also contains the property name and age. What I would like to understand, is how to (simply, if possible) form my gremlin query such that it nests of the vertex properties within the graph. Note that when I just run g.V("customerId"), the response does contain these properties.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should always specific exactly the data that you want returned in a traversal. Even for something as simple as:

```
g.V('customerId')
```

you should really prefer:

```
g.V('customerId').valueMap('name','age')
```

It's really no different in SQL where you likely wouldn't do

```
SELECT * FROM customer
```

but instead

```
SELECT name, age FROM customer
```

As for your question, you just need to specify the data you want back, so use the `by()` modulator for the `path()`:

```
g.V('customerId').
  out().
  path().
    by(valueMap('name','age'))
```

That of course assumes your `out()` is also a "customer", if not, just add a second `by()` with the specific fields required for that. The `by()` modulators are applied in round-robin fashion. If you'd like a slightly cleaner bit of JSON to deal with you might instead use `project()` like:

```
g.V('customerId').
  out().
  path().
    by(project('name','age').
         by('name').
         by('age'))
```

as that will kill out the embedded lists that `valueMap()` adds in to properly account for multi-properties.

As of TinkerPop 3.4.4, you would also consider `elementMap()`-step which includes more of the structure of the graph element.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').elementMap()
==>[id:1,label:person,name:marko,age:29]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').elementMap('name')
==>[id:1,label:person,name:marko]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').properties('name').elementMap()
==>[id:0,key:name,value:marko]
gremlin> g.E(11).elementMap()
==>[id:11,label:created,IN:[id:3,label:software],OUT:[id:4,label:person],weight:0.4]
```

Comment: Is there any way to include this data within a vertex or edge type in the gList? The query additions you gave me return everything in g:Map s

We're hoping for some data homogeneity so that we can have some consistency in our outputs and thus a DRY JSON unmarshaler.

Comment: You should look to standard collections when returning data. That goes back to my point about being explicit in what you return. There is no "partial" concept of a graph element (i.e. returning a `Vertex` with just some of the properties) and as you've seen in your query we will "detach" that vertex so that all you get is id/label. we refer to that form of the vertex as a "reference" vertex and in the future that's all TinkerPop will return for all traversals (already works that way in some graph implementations and TinkerPop serializers).

Comment: If your'e wondering why we consider "full" vertices "bad", you have to consider multi-properties. Imagine a vertex with a million properties on it and you accidentally return that unfiltered in a `path()` - that will be a costly day of serialization to return that result

Comment: Alright. fair enough. I appreciate you explaining that to me. One further question I have: how do I add the vertex ID in the "project(...)"? I tried just adding an argument "id" but that didn't seem to work. Based on our implementation it's fairly trivial to unmarshal the map into the vertex properties but without a primary key I can't identify the vertex to which the mapped attributes refer to.

Comment: it's just `by(T.id)` or simply `by(id)` if `T` is statically imported